# QCoreApplication error

Tags: pyqgis, importerror

In 3.2 and now 3.2.1 I get a Python error:

```
ImportError
cannot import name 'QCoreApplication'
```

I also see a yellow line highlighted as the problem line:
 from qgis.core import

Any ideas?

Comment: `QCoreApplication` should be imported from PyQt, not from `qgis` itself. Try `from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QCoreApplication`

Answer (score 2):

As German said in a comment, you need to change your imports from

`from qgis.core import QCoreApplication`

to

`from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QCoreApplication`